# Is there way I can use the onpress function of headerRight on the other component using React Native

Tags: react-native

I have problem, I don't know what this called but I give some explanations to you guys. I have module where I need to put check icon on the top of header of mobile, then if the user will **Press or OnPress** the icon, The modal will pop up.

My Question is:
**How to Access or Call the headerRight Onpress function to my Registration Component**

On my Navigation Component Stack.Screen:

```
headerRight: ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent: "flex-end",paddingRight:10,width: 120}}>
    <TouchableOpacity
       
        onPress={() => console.log("Fire Here!") }
        >
        <Icon type="font-awesome" name="check" size={20} color="white" />

        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
),
```

Registration Component:

```
class Register extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    
}

render() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[{ backgroundColor: '#ffff' }]}>
 
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

}

[image: My Current Output]

I Appreciated your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set header from within the Registration Component

```
const RegistrationComponent = ({navigation}) => {

    useEffect(()=>{
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => <Your headerRight Component/>
            })},[])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[{ backgroundColor: '#ffff' }]}>
 
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Comment: I would put it inside a useEffect inside the Registration Component

Comment: can you please explain more very appreciated

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: HI Gilad, why did you change the export the component inside Registration?

Comment: I didn't just converted it to functional component syntax because that's what I'm used to you can do the same thing with your class component

Comment: how to use it on the class component, this is my new learning sorry for that

Comment: apparently you want to use `componentDidMount` for class components in place of `useEffect`. let me know if that works

Comment: question. inside of my headerRight there is OnPress how can i use that onpress on my functional component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226378/discussion-between-gilad-shnoor-and-devge).